How to make a Sankey diagram with ggsankeyfier with a factor on the y-axis?
I'm using ggsankeyfier functions to make a Sankey diagram, which may not be the best solution for this but it is the best I have so far.
I've managed to create this plot:

from this example data:
t = data.frame(client = rep(c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g'), each = 4), 
               year = rep(2021:2024,7), 
               class = sample(0:3,size = 28,replace = T,prob = c(0.6,0.3,0.09,0.1)))

t %>% pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = class) %>% 
  mutate(final_class = 1) %>% 
  pivot_stages_longer(as.character(2021:2024), values_from = 'final_class') %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = stage, y = final_class, group = node, connector = connector, edge_id = edge_id))+
  geom_sankeyedge(aes(fill = node),position = pos, ncp = 1) +
  geom_sankeynode(aes(fill = node),position = pos) +
  geom_text(aes(label = str_wrap(node, 20)), position = pos_text, stat = "sankeynode",
            hjust = 0, cex = 2) +
  theme_minimal()

My goal is to track the flux of client between classes across years. This plot is ok for my purposes but I have two problems with it: It involves the creation of this final class variable, which seems really redundant. The plot also puts nodes in increasing order, I'd like to have them by class order (0 on the bottom, 3 on top, etc.). I tried to set y=node, however this loses the width of the nodes.
What could I be doing better?

in geom_sankeyedge() there is supposed to be an order option to do it as_is which might arrange it in the order you need.

Could you please check the code in the question (in a fresh instance of R) to confirm that it is reproducible. Object pos may be missing. Also add packages used in the example. Thanks.
